# Inheritance issue in python with a python tree library (anytree)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, tree

When I instanciate several nodes, I notice that default attributes which are not specified are then shared between different instanciations. Why ?

```
from anytree import NodeMixin

class TaskBase:

    def __init__(self, name: str = "default_name", id: int = 1, dependency: str = ""):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.dependency = dependency


class Task(TaskBase, NodeMixin):

    def __init__(self, name: str = "default_name", id: int = 1, parent=None, children=None):
        super().__init__(name=name, id=id)
        self.parent = parent
        if children:
            self.children = children

if __name__ == "__main__":
    task0 = Task(id=1)
    task1 = Task(id=2, parent=task0)
    task2 = Task(id=3, parent=task0)
```

In the console, here are the results of several tests :

```
>>> task0 is task1
False

>>> task0.children is task1.children
False

>>> task0.name is task1.name
True

>>> task0.id is task1.id
False
```

Why ***task0.name*** does point to the same object as ***task1.name*** while task0 and task1 are two different objects ?

Comment: This behaviour has nothing to do with inheritance. When two references to strings point to the same address, they are "identical" (`is`).

Answer (score 0):

check this more understanding about **is** keyword [is](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not)

```
>>  class Task():
...     def __init__(self, name: str = "default_name"):
...         self.name = name
... 
task0 = Task('name0')

>>  task1 = Task('name1')
task2 = Task('name1')

>>  task0.name is task1.name
False

>>  task1.name is task2.name
True
```

task0.name and task1.name are same object, because name of each tasks are located the same place, but task0 and task1 are difference object, because they are located different places of memory